# First order logic and algebraic structures. Reference request.

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, logic

I have been encountering many results on logic-related properties of algebraic structures such as elementary equivalence, axiomatizability, definability, etc. The problem is that when I see the proof or a sketch of the proof, I understand every third word or less. What should I read to get proper understaning of the methods used in such proofs? I would most apperciate a book focused mainly on algebra and first order logic.

Comment: Any book with "model theory" and "introduction" in the title should work.

Comment: +1 Chris however, personally I found delving straight into model theory can be a bit difficult and a text such as Geoffrey Hunter's [Metalogic](http://www.ucpress.edu/book.php?isbn=9780520023567) can ease up the transition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A useful (and free!) book is *Fundamentals of Model Theory* by Weiss and D'Mello.

I second the recommendation for Hodges' *Model Theory*. It is long-run more useful than his *Shorter Model Theory*.

Marker's *Model Theory* is also very good.

Comment: I second the suggestion of Marker's *Model Theory: An Introduction*. It is especially focused on algebraic structures.

Answer (score 2):

An excellent choice is Wilfred Hodges textbook *Model Theory*, which goes into much further detail than most alternatives, and has many illuminating notes that will help you to "think like a model theorist" (and some good jokes to boot!) Also extremely useful are the many survey articles in the *Handbook of Mathematical Logic* (edited by J. Barwise)