# I would like some textbook recommendations for model theory

Tags: reference-request, logic, model-theory

I am a 3rd year undergraduate math student and would like to study [model theory.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory) . I have some background with set theory, ordinals etc and also with mathematical logic.

This is purely for self study and textbooks that are clear and perhaps with a good amount of examples would be appreciated.

Comment: You can find a good biblio in *SEP* [Model Theory](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/model-theory/) and [First-order Model Theory](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/modeltheory-fo/). There are less expensive Dover reprints of some "classics", like: C.Chang and J.Keisler, 3rd ed 1990, *Model Theory*; and J.L.Bell and A.B.Slomson, 1969, *Models and Ultraproducts: An Introduction*. Then you have : W.Hodges, 1997, *A Shorter Model Theory*, Cambridge University Press.

Comment: [This thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100531/first-order-logic-and-algebraic-structures-reference-request/100543#100543) has several recommendations of introductory model theory texts. *Fundamentals of Model Theory* by Weiss and D'Mello [is available for free download](http://www.math.toronto.edu/weiss/model_theory.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Learning Model Theory](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161924/learning-model-theory)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not take a look on the sections on model theory in the reading Guide on math logic which you can download from http://www.logicmatters.net/tyl ?

Yes, Marker's text is standard; but it is tough. The Guide suggests a few texts that bridge the gap between the entry-level model theory in standard first math logic courses and the advanced text by Marker. The headline news is that Hodges's *Shorter Model Theory* is a particularly good intermediate choice: but there is a lot more said in the Guide.

Answer (score 4):

A canonical choice would be [Model Theory : An Introduction](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Model_Theory_An_Introduction.html?id=QieAHk--GCcC&redir_esc=y) by Marker.

Also, if you read french, there is a more advance but marvelous book : [Cours de théories des modèles](http://books.google.fr/books?id=QuHuAAAAMAAJ&q=poizat%20th%C3%A9orie%20des%20mod%C3%A8les&dq=poizat%20th%C3%A9orie%20des%20mod%C3%A8les&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=zDxFU4HxKYXnswa20YCoDQ&ved=0CDMQ6wEwAA) (Une introduction à la Logique Mathématique contemporaine) by Poizat.

Comment: @Paprika - there is an english translation of [Poizat](http://www.amazon.it/Course-Model-Theory-Introduction-Contemporary/dp/0387986553)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I was not aware of this translation, thanks. (I hope he kept in english his very special way of writing which makes half the fun of reading him in the french edition).