# What is the best easy introduction to model theory?

Tags: model-theory, book-recommendation

Model theory looks super complicated, what is a good simple book I can read, even if no exhaustive, that can help me understand more advanced textbooks? (I need it for self study)

Comment: I haven't read this, but it looks quite basic: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Invitation-Model-Theory-Jonathan-Kirby/dp/1316615553/

Comment: There are some MSE posts about this; see for example [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161924/learning-model-theory) and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746617/i-would-like-some-textbook-recommendations-for-model-theory?rq=1). As you can see in the answers, Marker's book is usually a top choice.

Answer (score 2):

A good introduction to the subject for me has been David Marker's *Model Theory: an Introduction*. What I appreciate about the book is his application of the abstract theory to more "concrete" algebraic examples, such as dense linear orders or fields.

Comment: I agree with your latter point. However, IMHO, it is not $\textit{that}$ basic, for someone who's looking for a first book.

Comment: You are probably right, I'm just not aware of much outside of that book or other really specialized books which are inappropriate for a beginner.